# How to avoid repeated jobs (one per core) when I'm trying to launch different threads?

Tags: multithreading, perl, parallel-processing, multicore, slurm

I'm processing multiple big independent files (same process for each file, no communication between processes). So, I have a situation that seems  great for parallel multicore processing. And, in fact, I have access to a nice server (Scientific Linux -Red Hat Enterprise-) with multiple cores.

I'm trying to write some scripts with Perl in order to take profit of these cores. I tried both the [`threads`](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html) module and [`Parallel::ForkManager`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager). I launch the works to the server using `sbatch`, where I can define the number of tasks (cores) I will use (and the memory I will take, etc.). Nevertheless, when  I launched a job selecting X number of tasks, the job is not divided between cores, but always carry out repeatedly (X times, once in each core). I'm sure I'm missing something big (and basic!) but after one week going in all the directions, I don't realize what it is. What's going wrong???

Here is a sample Perl script (`test.pl`):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w 

use strict;
use threads;
use Benchmark qw(:hireswallclock);

my $starttime = Benchmark->new;
my $finishtime;
my $timespent;
my $num_of_threads = 4;

my @threads = initThreads();
foreach(@threads){
    $_ = threads->create(\&doOperation);
}
foreach(@threads){
    $_->join();
}
$finishtime = Benchmark->new;
$timespent = timediff($finishtime,$starttime);
print "\nDone!\nSpent ". timestr($timespent);


sub initThreads{
    my @initThreads;
    for(my $i = 1;$i<=$num_of_threads;$i++){
        push(@initThreads,$i);
    }
    return @initThreads;
}
sub doOperation{
    # Get the thread id. Allows each thread to be identified.
    my $id = threads->tid();
    my $i = 0;
    while($i < 100000000){
            $i++
    }
    print "Thread $id done!\n";
    # Exit the thread
    threads->exit();
}
```

And here, an example of an `sbatch` script used to launch it:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
#SBATCH --job-name=prueba
#SBATCH -e slurm-%j.out
#SBATCH --ntasks=4
#SBATCH --mem=12G
srun perl -w test.pl
```

The output (as I said, it seems that the whole process have been repeated once in each core):

```
Thread 4 done!
Thread 1 done!
Thread 1 done!
Thread 4 done!
Thread 3 done!
Thread 3 done!
Thread 1 done!
Thread 3 done!
Thread 1 done!
Thread 4 done!
Thread 4 done!
Thread 3 done!
Thread 2 done!
Thread 2 done!
Thread 2 done!
Thread 2 done!

Done!
Spent 36.1026 wallclock secs (36.02 usr +  0.00 sys = 36.02 CPU)
```

Comment: Why do you think that the programs are not being run in more than one core?

Comment: In fact I'm thinking that yes: the Perl script is running in more than one core (as it has been defined with the sbatch script, in four cores). The problem is that the whole script (with all the threads) is running four times, once in each core. The cores are no taking only one Perl-thread but the four (I'm not able to find the way to divide the job -in fact i'm multiplying it by the number of threads defined in the sbatch script-).

Comment: If you question is 'why I'm thinking that the programs are not being run in more than one core' if I don't define it in the sbatch script, I think it because the processing time when -ntasks in the sbatch is 1 is the same using "threads" than not using it (or using "Parallel::ForkManager" when I did it).

Comment: Maybe that's a limit imposed by [`sbatch`](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/slurm/sbatch.html)? What if you set `--cpus-per-task`?

Comment: Bingo! With --cpu-per-task i just get an output for every thread (not four as before!) and I reduce the amount of processing time (from 18.8796 wallclock secs without "threads" to 8.90519 using it -I would expect a four times reduction by dividing in 4 cores-). I think you got it, mob; I think I will be now able to multi-thread my jobs. Thanks a lot!

Comment: PS: time to review SBATCH a little bit deeper. I figured out I needed to reserve "tasks" for the multicore processing (making the equivalence between tasks and cores for sbatch) when I needed cpu's (I figure out there is only one task for sbatch, the Perl script that I'm launching). Shame ·_· ...

Comment: As an aside, I'd find something like `push @thr, threads->create(\&doOp) for 1 .. $num_threads` (or a `map {}` equivalent) rather clearer than the rigmarole with loop-assignment to the aliased `$_` after calling the dubiously named `initThreads()`.

Comment: If used for Bioinformatics you should read: http://www.biostars.org/p/63816/

Answer (score 3):

With `--ntasks=4`, srun will launch 4 identical Perl processes. What you want is `--ntasks=1` and `--cpu-per-task=4` so that Slurm allocates four cores on one node for your job.